# How do you spend a P2SH transaction?

Tags: bitcoin-core, raw-transaction, p2sh

I've been running into a lot of trouble getting a transaction to spend coins in a multisig address.

I create the raw transaction
When I go to sign, I get "Operation not valid with the correct stack size"

I'm using core, and the codes are here.

First, check if it's good.

```
bitcoin-cli decoderawtransaction 0100000001d2aba456546be8f5223802112637e484c5d94118dfe560fa23de06fb37e621dd0000000000ffffffff01107a0700000000001976a914a4f29e1c8f592021fd79eda1be85c96a9a8d349a88ac00000000
{
    "txid" : "e71006c60dbfa2793710d5cf866d1b6b89ba80bc41634031d927738c40ae8228",
    "version" : 1,
    "locktime" : 0,
    "vin" : [
        {
            "txid" : "dd21e637fb06de23fa60e5df1841d9c584e4372611023822f5e86b5456a4abd2",
            "vout" : 0,
            "scriptSig" : {
                "asm" : "",
                "hex" : ""
            },
            "sequence" : 4294967295
        }
    ],
    "vout" : [
        {
            "value" : 0.00490000,
            "n" : 0,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 a4f29e1c8f592021fd79eda1be85c96a9a8d349a OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex" : "76a914a4f29e1c8f592021fd79eda1be85c96a9a8d349a88ac",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "1G3ATq31k5SrGdqucXKqA9dHbzS3wJHzbc"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And then we go to sign.

```
bitcoin-cli signrawtransaction 0100000001d2aba456546be8f5223802112637e484c5d94118dfe560fa23de06fb37e621dd0000000000ffffffff01107a0700000000001976a914a4f29e1c8f592021fd79eda1be85c96a9a8d349a88ac00000000
{
    "hex" : "0100000001d2aba456546be8f5223802112637e484c5d94118dfe560fa23de06fb37e621dd000000009200483045022100eaae5737ab000f614ce73da11ba456b4467cf640ed881fd1fa90183d1d28c2e8022066c78bf750ae0a175f6ef116ecc3e4a0c18eda1aff9c951952f8f6e45a3521ad0147522102908921b30aa37fe6e522c528cca0ebcda9f0df4019301fa45bc3b3c7df60245a2103559dc92d6e44a98080d487e585b93278106249a166795584ae554a4275f059b752aeffffffff01107a0700000000001976a914a4f29e1c8f592021fd79eda1be85c96a9a8d349a88ac00000000",
    "complete" : false,
    "errors" : [
        {
            "txid" : "dd21e637fb06de23fa60e5df1841d9c584e4372611023822f5e86b5456a4abd2",
            "vout" : 0,
            "scriptSig" : "00483045022100eaae5737ab000f614ce73da11ba456b4467cf640ed881fd1fa90183d1d28c2e8022066c78bf750ae0a175f6ef116ecc3e4a0c18eda1aff9c951952f8f6e45a3521ad0147522102908921b30aa37fe6e522c528cca0ebcda9f0df4019301fa45bc3b3c7df60245a2103559dc92d6e44a98080d487e585b93278106249a166795584ae554a4275f059b752ae",
            "sequence" : 4294967295,
            "error" : "Operation not valid with the current stack size"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gavinandresen/3966071/raw/ca21870c190ba0e90c1a30673e790ef5acd207d2/TwoOfThree.sh for reference.

Comment: Do you have all of the keys necessary to spend this output? This looks like it signed with some of the keys, but you need another.

Comment: Is that what it means? I didnt even think that it signed part, it seems to give no sign of partial success. yes, i only have one of the required keys, but what part of that shows it partly signed?

Comment: Well, it's longer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Please, write up an answer and I will accept. What genius decided to code such a user-unfriendlt 'success'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get this error because Bitcoin has tried to validate the script, and failed, because not all of the signatures necessary were added in the previous `signrawtransaction`. You can also tell this because `complete` is false.

You need to take it to clients that have the other keys necessary, and run `signrawtransaction` on the transaction there too.

Comment: To further clarify, for future viewers, you can tell that the tx is partly signed by running the returned hash though `decoderawtransaction` and noting that you now have content in the vin scriptsig field. It really should have a message saying it was partly signed, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Drazisil Why do I get content in the scriptsig of vin?